# Why HTTPSReciever maxSize attribute default value is 10MB?

Tags: 2011

The default value in deployer config for https receiver's max size attribute value is  10MB.

**Why is the default set at only 10MB?**

We have seen many a times that when a page with a huge number of images is published, it fails. The resolution is to increase the max size.

**What is the upper limit of max size attribute?** 
**If there is a max limit for max size, then please tell why this max size value is felt to be safe for publishing.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what the upper limit is, and normally I set this value to something around 100MB. Publishing more than 100MB should call the attention of a sys admin anyway, as it may indicate a problem with content dependencies and/or how the editors are publishing content.

As to why is the default value "so low", I guess you can point to "legacy". Back in 2001/2002, 10MB was a rather large value for a package. It's easy to change it though.

What do you think should be the default value? 50? 100? 1GB?

Comment: I was thinking of a case where 100 components existing on a page with 3 multimedia link field. If image size sums to 0.5 MB per component then the package size will be nearly 55-60 MB. So 100 MB seems to be fine in such a scenario. But I questioned about max size because if number of component start attached on this page increase to 500 or 1000.

Comment: 100 components on a Page is not ideal or at least in my experience. It is unmanageable for authors and there is some fundamental design flaw (at least in my PoV).

Comment: @Ram that is right that it can be a design flaw. But the issue a very common issue. So i discussed

Comment: The default could be higher but traditionally this has been on par with IIS default values in IIS 6 default is 20MB, IIS7 default is 30MB. Rationale could be, it is 10MB is to keep the value less than IIS defaults as well backwards compatibility. Note, just changing this number to higher value is not just sufficient and you also need to increase the web server default sizes (IIS 7 - 30MB) as well.